# How can use Facebook login only from Django-allauth

Tags: django, django-models, facebook-login, django-allauth

I want to know how I can use only the facebook login method from django-allauth package and the rest to keep my login and register models that I customized for my need!
Just facebook login! Thanks!

Comment: You need to provide an attempted solution and explain what went wrong for people to help you.

Comment: The problem is that I don`t know how exactly I can do it...